# Using MouseOver and MouseOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys im working on my first website and im trying to implement a sliding menu using `jquery`.

This is what a got so far :

```
         <a href="javascript:void(0);"onmouseover="ShowBox();" onmouseout="HideBox();"">Show box<a>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowBox()
         {
           $("#SlideMenu").slideDown();   
         }
         function HideBox()
         {
           $("#SlideMenu").slideUp();
         }
         </script>
```

When i MouseOver the control my menu slides down but slides back up automatically.
What I would like is to let the user the time to select and option from the menu and if he doesn't, i would like the menu to close as soon as the mouse leaves the control.

Any idea why this isn't working ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it do when you leaves the mouse or hover the element? Does it give an error?

Comment: no it just act as if the mouse is away from the control although i didnt mouse at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your stuff without the inline JS, and remember to close the `<a>` element and use a ready function

```
<a id="test">Show box</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#test").on({
          mouseenter: function() {
             $("#SlideMenu").slideDown();
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
             $("#SlideMenu").slideUp();
          },
          click: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
   });
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/66NwJ/1/)

Comment: just changed my code for this but i dont get any effects anymore. just a Show Box label

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk - added a Fiddle to show it working, is that what you are after ?

Comment: Works perfectly in the fiddle.
Not at all in my code.
I use the Exact same code

Comment: The result in the fiddle is exactly what I need though

Comment: Try running `alert(typeof $)` right below the document.ready line, and see if the alert pops up ?

Comment: ooh and one more thing I didn't notice when I tested your fiddle, I need the Menu to stay open when I'm in it to. Not just when i'm on the  ShowBox control

Comment: Easy solution would be to do this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/66NwJ/2/), if for some reason you can't put the slided element inside the triggering element, some timeouts and a little trickery is needed.

Comment: I cant figure out why this isnt working ... what is the latest jquery version ?

Comment: That was it. ! 

The version -__- thanks SO MUCH for your help

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery I believe it would be beneficial for you to use something similar to:

```
$("#box").hover(
   function() {
      //.stop() to prevent propagation
      $(this).stop().animate({"bottom": "200px"}, "fast");                   
   },
   function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({"bottom": "0px"}, "fast");                  
   }
);
```

What this will mean is that whilst the mouse is over the menu, the menu will stay in its open position. When the mouse exits the menu it will close. Obviously change the id, and animation CSS values to suit your needs :)!

**Here is a working example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/V3PYs/1/

Comment: Why use animate when you could just use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`? Also, you failed to mention that you need to give the `<a>` element an ID of `box` in order for the above to work.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Using animate makes it very easy to alter, he could have his menu slide up, left, down, right, fade in, fade out etc.. But you're right this eliminates the need for a button to toggle the menu. I'll mention that thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Really there is no problem here - the script is doing exactly what you told it to. However, from what I understand, what you *want* is for the menu to stay open when you leave the "trigger" element *if* the user's mouse is now over the menu. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout=250;//timeout in milliseconds to wait before hiding the menu
var menuMouseout;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#trigger").hover(function(){
        $("#SlideMenu").slideDown();
    }, function(){
        menuMouseout=setTimeout("$('#SlideMenu').slideUp();", timeout);
    });

    $("#SlideMenu").hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(menuMouseout);
    }, function(){
        menuMouseout=setTimeout("$('#SlideMenu').slideUp();", timeout);
    });
});
</script>
```

This way, the user is left some time after mousing out of the trigger element to get to the menu. You might need to fiddle with the timeout, but this should work. I tested this and it seems to be working. Just be sure, if necessary, to wrap this in `$(document).ready` to make sure all elements are loaded and ready.

Demo: http://www.dstrout.net/pub/menu.htm

Comment: same here youre code works perfectly in the exemple. Not in my code...  this is weird

Comment: Did you make sure to change the ID in the code from #trigger to whatever the actual ID of your trigger element is? Take a close look at my demo to make sure you're not missing anything, since that is working for you.

Comment: I'm sorry its my fault. My problem with your solution and adeneo's was the Jquery version I was including..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery this would be the proper way to go about it:

```
<a href="#" id="showBoxHref">Show box</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#showBoxHref").hover(function() {
        $(this).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

(just copy/paste this in and it should work)

Comment: This doesnt work. Now i dont get sliding at all. Do i need to add an event to the <a> tag?

Comment: Nope, you need to see my answer, and close the element first.

Comment: Oops, couple typoes, fixing. @adeneo: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: It works now but still the same problem. As soon as the menu is down , it slides back up. No matter where i put the mouse. Even if I don't move it at all :(